# How to count touch movement

Tags: android, touch

I'm writing a program allow user to draw line or curve by touching.
But when user move the finger very fast from the point near to point 1,
to the point near to point 2 and vice and versa in 8-9 times, the screen must
be locked. And I want to know how to lock the screen at correct time.
Please help me.